# what's the matter of my shadowMap?

Tags: three.js

[image]

My shadowMap is too little,what's the matter?

Comment: Looks like you didn't set up the shadow map camera. I believe it's different for different lights. Either post some code or at least specify which light you are using (looks like it could be directional). Please edit the question it's not formatted well (attach code)

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not set the shadowmap camera (correctly).

[From the docs:](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow)

> The default is an OrthographicCamera with left and bottom set to -5, right and top set to 5, the near clipping plane at 0.5 and the far clipping plane at 500.

Meaning:

```
yourLight.shadow.camera.left = -500 //(default is -5)
yourLight.shadow.camera.right = 500 //(default is 5)
yourLight.shadow.camera.top = -500 //(default is -5)
yourLight.shadow.camera.bottom = 500 //(default is 5)

//not sure if this is needed, the docs do not mention it even though they are changing the projection so probably not needed
yourLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```